# Authentication against Power Bi in Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, powerbi

I have an application developed with ASP MVC using Azure AD authentication. This application is supposed to post data to Power BI. I have tried to follow this tutorial: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-a-client-app/ , it works and it is almost exactly what I need.

The problem is that it uses Native App authentication, and my application is a web app. Furthermore, my app is already authenticated against Azure AD, and I do not want to ask user credentials second time.

I assume that I can somehow get bearer token from current Owin Context, and use it to authenticate against Power BI. Is this correct and how can I do it?

My app is simple app generated by VS template with AD authentication turned on, so there is no sense to post any code.

*Updated*
Ah, ok just a bit of details (let me know if you need more):
Signing in (generated by VS) is :

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
```

Authentication type is `"OpenIdConnect"`

`Startup.Auth.cs` is:

```
 app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

 app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri
                });
```

**One more thing, I'm not sure it's clear from the post. My aim is to authenticate to PowerBi with current logged-in user credentials. Each user in my system will have his own report to display in the web app**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go for `Authenticate your web app` or `Azure Active Directory tenant`instead of Registering the client app with Power BI.

**Tutorials**

[Authenticate your web app](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/)

[Azure Active Directory tenant](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-create-an-azure-active-directory-tenant/)

**Sample App**

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/get-started-web-app-asp.net

Comment: I've seen those tutorials and looks like I just didn't understand what was happening there. I didn't want to authorize twice and I thought that the redirect to `https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/` always performs a mandatory authorization, but it looks like this is not the case. In case if the app is already authenticated the redirect to this url will redirect back to `redirectUri` skipping the whole authorization screen, so this is exactly what I was looking for